# Vault-agent-injector get role-id and secret-id

Tags: go, kubernetes, vault

#### Question: Automating the acquisition of `secret-id` for `AppRole` using Vault-agent-injector in Kubernetes

##### Goal:

My task is to set up an automatic process for obtaining `secret-id` for `AppRole` in a Kubernetes environment. To achieve this, I plan to utilize Vault capabilities in conjunction with the Vault-agent-injector mechanism. Currently, the agent-injector configuration is implemented to inject secrets directly into the environment variables of applications.

##### Issue:

It is necessary to develop a solution for automatically obtaining a new `secret-id` for the specific role `devtest` at the moment of deploying services through Kubernetes Deployment. The main task is to ensure that services, after their authorization using the AppRole mechanism, can securely access the required secrets. An important aspect is the use of one-time `secret-id`, which will enhance security and ensure isolation of secrets between different instances of the service.

##### Background:

In the current process, the following command in Vault is used to generate `secret-id`:

bash

`vault write -f auth/approle/role/devtest/secret-id`

The main question is the possibility of integrating and automating this process in the context of deploying services using Kubernetes Deployment and Vault-agent-injector.

##### Example of Deployment configuration:

yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-test-service
  ...
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-pre-populate-only: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: 'true'
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: 'test-app'
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-.venv: |
          {{- with secret "test/data/database/postgres" -}}
            {{- range $k, $v := .Data.data }}
              export {{$k}}={{$v}}
            {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
  ...       
      containers:
          ...
          args:
              [ 'source /vault/secrets/.venv && rm -rf /vault/secrets/.venv && /app' ]
          ...
```

##### Additional context:

The implementation of reading secrets directly in the service using AppRole authorization is already done. The goal is to ensure the uniqueness of `secret-id` for each new instance of the service at its deployment, thereby improving security and managing access to secrets.

Comment: Please update the full yaml you are using for your workload, as well as the relevant configuration files for the injector agent. Otherwise it's too vague and very hard to help you